# Error 3203 restoring SQL Server backup: The data is invalid

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, restore

I am trying to restore a .bak file (backup taken on SQL Server 2008 R2, compatibility level 100). I am restoring the backup on SQL Server 2012 edition. I get the below error. Unfortunately the original DB from where the DB was backed up is no longer available. I am new on this project. I was given the bak file on a thumb drive.

Any suggestions on how I can restore the DB to 2012 ?

> Restore of database 'TstDB' failed.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Read on ***13(The data is invalid.)

This is all is the error message. When I run `RESTORE VERIFYONLY`, I get the below error:

> Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Read on "C:****" failed: 13(The data is invalid.)
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

`RESTORE HEADERONLY` was successful. When I run restore database with stats=1 I get the below:

> 10 percent processed.
>   20 percent processed.
>   [...]
>   70 percent processed.
>   80 percent processed.
>   Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Read on "C:\ccc.bak" failed: 13(The data is invalid.)
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Answer (score 1):

Try running a `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` or `RESTORE HEADERONLY`. If these run successfully, that would prove that SQL Server is successfully accessing the .bak file. (And rule out some sort of permission issue.)

If that is successful, try running your `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` and `RESTORE DATABASE` with `STATS=1`. If it continues to fail in the same spot each time, it would probably indicate that your backup is corrupt, and you're out of luck.

If it fails in a different spot each time, it could be an issue with reliability of the location where your .bak is saved.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*Community Wiki answer added to document contributions originally left as comments*</sub>

From [KASSQLDBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44801/kasqldba):

> As per the posted error, it seems like the file may be corrupted. Please read the following to see if it helps:
>
> [Affordable Solution To Repair Corrupt SQL Backup File](https://web.archive.org/web/20140831033502/https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Affordable-Solution-To-43165a47) (TechNet Gallery Third-Party tool)

From [Kin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/8783/kin):

> Can you copy the backup to another drive NOT `C:\` and then try to restore it? If it fails, its definitely corrupted and you are out of luck.

---

See also [SQL Server Troubleshooting: How to detect and speedily fix SQL Database corruption](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51634.sql-server-troubleshooting-how-to-detect-and-speedily-fix-sql-database-corruption.aspx) on Microsoft TechNet.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to detach it from the 2008 R2 server, copying the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files over to the 2012 server and re-attaching them to it?

It doesn't solve the backup error I know. It would get the database over to the 2012 server and if it attaches successfully would tell you that its good.

Comment: From OP: Unfortunately the original DB from where the DB was backed up is no longer available.